# Pandas merge dataframe with conditions depends on value in a column

Tags: python, pandas, merge

a help will be appreciated.

I have 2 DataFrames.

The first data frame consisted of an activity schedule of person,`schedule`, as following:

```
PersonID   Person      Origin    Destination
3-1          1          A           B
3-1          1          B           A
13-1         1          C           D
13-1         1          D           C
13-2         2          A           B
13-2         2          B           A
```

And I have another DataFrame, `household`, containing the details of the person/agent.

```
PersonID1    Age1    Gender1     PersonID2     Age2    Gender2
3-1           20       M           NaN         NaN       NaN
13-1          45       F          13-2          17        M
```

I want to perform a VLOOKUP on these two using pd.merge. Since the lookup(merge) will depends on the person's ID, I tried to that with a condition.

```
def merging(row):
   if row['Person'] == 1:
       row = pd.merge(row, household, how='left', left_on=['PersonID'], right_on=['Age1', 'Gender1'])
   else:
       row = pd.merge(row, household, how='left', left_on=['PersonID'], right_on=['Age2','Gender2'])
   return row

schedule_merged = schedule.apply(merging, axis=1)
```

However, for some reason, it just doesn't work. The error says `ValueError: len(right_on) must equal len(left_on)`. I'm aiming to make this kind of data in the end:

```
PersonID   Person      Origin    Destination    Age    Gender
3-1          1          A           B           20       M
3-1          1          B           A           20       M
13-1         1          C           D           45       F
13-1         1          D           C           45       F
13-2         2          A           B           17       M
13-2         2          B           A           17       M
```

I think I messed up the `pd.merge` lines. While it might be more efficient to use VLOOKUP in Excel, it's just to heavy for my PC, since I have to apply this for a hundred thousand data. How could I do this properly? Thanks!

Comment: Not sure whether this is the most elegant way, but I would suggest first splitting the schedule dataframe by person. Then I would merge the person1df with the first 3 columns of the household dataframe and person2df with the other columns. Only then I would remerge the dataframes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is how I would do it if the real dataset is not more complicated than the given example. Other wise I would suggest looking at pd.melt() for more complex unpivoting.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

# Create Dummy schedule DataFrame
d = {'PersonID': ['3-1', '3-1', '13-1', '13-1', '13-2', '13-2'], 'Person': ['1', '1', '1', '1', '2', '2'], 'Origin': ['A', 'B', 'C', 'D', 'A', 'B'], 'Destination': ['B', 'A', 'D', 'C', 'B', 'A']}
schedule = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
schedule

# Create Dummy houshold DataFrame
d = {'PersonID1': ['3-1', '13-1'], 'Age1': ['20', '45'], 'Gender1': ['M', 'F'], 'PersonID2': [np.nan, '13-2'], 'Age2': [np.nan, '17'], 'Gender2': [np.nan, 'M']}
household = pd.DataFrame(data=d)
household

# Select columns for PersonID1 and rename columns
household1 = household[['PersonID1', 'Age1', 'Gender1']]
household1.columns = ['PersonID', 'Age', 'Gender']
# Select columns for PersonID1 and rename columns
household2 = household[['PersonID2', 'Age2', 'Gender2']]
household2.columns = ['PersonID', 'Age', 'Gender']

# Concat them together
household_new = pd.concat([household1, household2])

# Merge houshold and schedule df together on PersonID
schedule = schedule.merge(household_new, how='left', left_on='PersonID', right_on='PersonID', validate='many_to_one')
```

**Output**

```
PersonID   Person      Origin    Destination    Age    Gender
3-1          1          A           B           20       M
3-1          1          B           A           20       M
13-1         1          C           D           45       F
13-1         1          D           C           45       F
13-2         2          A           B           17       M
13-2         2          B           A           17       M
```

Comment: Worked like a charm! just understood that `validate='many_to_one'` and I think that's just what I needed! Thanks!

Comment: Yeah the `validate` parameter is great and I try to always use it as a best practice to make sure you are merging the way you think you are. [pandas.DataFrame.merge](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html)